# Any good implementation of Qt + Lisp?

Tags: qt, lisp, common-lisp, qt4.6

I was searching for a good Qt + Lisp implementation on the internet and couldn't find any. Most projects were closed down or so.

Does anybody know of a good Common Lisp + Qt integration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is QtJambi in Clojure, but I imagine that isn't what you are looking for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

CommonQT

http://common-lisp.net/project/commonqt/

is a binding that may be able to help you.

Comment: Take a look at Shinmera's Qtools which builds builds on top of CommonQT - https://github.com/Shinmera/qtools (or docs https://shinmera.github.io/qtools/). It provides very useful abstractions, allows you to build self-contained executables easily and still lets you use the bare CommonQT/Smoke stack if you want, so it's a win-win situation.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to CommonQt, http://password-taxi.at/EQL is the page for Embedded Qt Lisp, a project that uses ECL to drive CL. I haven't tried it, but it seems interesting.

Comment: IMHO this si by far the nicest Qt for any lisp. Too bad it is ECL specific and thus not portable to other CL implementations